# Using TimeSpan object in Google Charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I'm passing some C# TimeSpan objects that I would like to use with Google Charts (stacked columns showing the lengths of times for each TimeSpan).

Most or all of the examples I've found are using DateTime, or the range between 2 DateTime objects to get a span of time.

I would, however, much prefer to use TimeSpan in this case. Is there a simple way this could be done?

Comment: Just convert the timespan object to a single unit of time, like seconds, minutes, or hours and represent it as a single number.  Pick a unit that makes sense for your application.  For example, don't use seconds if your recorded data is only accurate to minutes.

Comment: This is what I decided to go with over the weekend, thanks for the reply.